# Copy multiple cells from excel column to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Example]

Is there a way to copy multiple selected cells from excel as shown below? It always copies the whole range from the first selected cell to the last cell, rather than copying the values from selected cells.

A VBA code will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will help, this will copy the specified ranges to the clipboard so you can paste them into Notepad:

```
Sub CopyToClipboard()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
ws.Range("B11:B12,B14,B18,B20,B22").Copy
'copy range to clipboard
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

A possible workaround for this would be to use a Temp worksheet and add the selected values into it and then copy that range into the Clipboard, a little long winded, but it would work:

```
Sub CopyToClipboard()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
Dim work As Worksheet
Dim arr() As Variant
i = 0

For Each work In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If work.Name = "Temp" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        work.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next
'if Temp worksheet exists then delete it

For Each c In Selection
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To i)
    arr(i) = c.Value
Next
'above add the values from selection to an array

Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws2.Name = "Temp"
'add a temporary worksheet

For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    ws2.Cells(x, 1).Value = arr(x)
Next x
'copy values from array into temp worksheet

LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ws2.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Copy
'copy continuous range from Temp worksheet
End Sub
```

Comment: As basically the same +1. Column B though to match OP :-)

Comment: @Xabier I want some automated method to specify the cells, because it is not the same selection every time.

Comment: If I use Selection.Copy, it would copy the whole range from B11 to B22

Comment: @SajW so what is the criteria to select the cells? Are you looking for specific numbers or any other way to identify which cells you are wanting?

Comment: @SajW I've updated my answer with a workaround, not the most efficient, but it would work for the task in hand, hope it is useful for you. :)